# TinyMCE 4.x editor.windowManager.open autoscroll and overflow issue

Tags: tinymce-4, wordpress-3.9

I am having problem with TinyMCE 4.x custom plugin js for editor.windowManager.open.
I used autoScroll: true, height: 500, width: 800 and few more parameters but only height and width gets effect.
I can see the scrollbar but it doesn't work and body content are visible.

```
editor.windowManager.open( {
     autoScroll: true,
     height: 500,
     width: 800,
     resizable : true,
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. It's because wordpress adds the following rule in editor.min.css:

```
    .mce-window .mce-container-body.mce-abs-layout {
        overflow: visible;
    }
```

To fix it just add a class to your window:

```
var win = editor.windowManager.open( {
    autoScroll: true,
    width: 670,
    height: 500,
    classes: 'myAwesomeClass-panel'
});
```

And target it with some css:

```
.mce-window.mce-container.mce-myAwesomeClass-panel .mce-container-body.mce-abs-layout {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Adding a class to your panel and applying css to only that will likely prevent any interference with built in wp stuff.

Comment: I didn't know how to use var win = editor.windowManager.open() but managed to work. Thanks

Comment: Brilliant! Just to add - it might be useful to use "id" instead of classes for more 'exact targeting':

JS:

  var win = editor.windowManager.open( {
    autoScroll: true,
    width: 670,
    height: 500,
    id: 'myMcePanel'
  });

CSS:

  #myMcePanel-body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

Answer (score 0):

I also have same problem but i solve it by using the following code change in css location:wp-includes/css/editor.min.css

```
.mce-window .mce-container-body.mce-abs-layout{
    overflow: auto;
 }
```